# Compress a local file by php before storing it in the database

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I want to compress a file in php before sending it to the db.

One solution

```
$statement = $pdo->prepare('INSERT INTO test(datablob) VALUES(?);');
$data = gzcompress(file_get_contents('file.txt'));
$statement->bindParam(1,$data,PDO::PARAM_LOB);
$statement->execute();
```

But I don't want to read the file into memory. Without compression it would look like:

```
$statement = $pdo->prepare('INSERT INTO test(datablob) VALUES(?);');
$data = fopen('file.txt');
$statement->bindParam(1,$data,PDO::PARAM_LOB);
$statement->execute();
```

**How can i compress a local available file in php to add it to the database (Without storing the content in memory)?**

I'm thinking about a solution about wrapping a file Stream into a compression stream and bind this "compressed" stream handle to the PDO statement. But how would this look like?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found myself an easy solution with PHP/stream_filters:

```
$statement = $pdo->prepare('INSERT INTO test(datablob) VALUES(?);');
$data = fopen('file.txt','rb');
stream_filter_append($data,'zlib.deflate',STREAM_FILTER_READ);
$statement->bindParam(1,$data,PDO::PARAM_LOB);
$statement->execute();
```